# Lex/Yacc Parser to parse file which has headers and values in column

Tags: c++, bison, yacc, lex

I am trying to write a Parser for a log file which has number of headers and values associated with each header. The format is similar to the below:

```
Field1 Field2 Field3 
---------------------
Val1   Val2  Val3
```

Can anybody help me with the lex file to scan the following format?

Comment: lex/yacc is probably overkill for this problem. You can do it with about 5 lines of C++.

Answer (score 1):

This will identify a token "identifier" in the lex

```
    id [a-z A-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

You could use this grammar for the parser.

```
    S : E '\n' V  {printf("Accepted\n");}
    E : E ' ' ID;
    V : V ' ' ID;
```

`ID` must be returned from the lex as a token

But I think you should rather study the Flex and the Bison tutorials. That'd be enough. If you are using Linux, the info page of Bison has rich details.

Comment: thanks for the info... but I need help with the lex file.. how can i map each field with its value?

Comment: You can map the fields with the values only if you can think of a grammar to do so. The grammar that I have given you will only identify the headers and the values as separate fields.

Comment: If you have a fixed number of headers, this is possible. Otherwise, better use some c code as @loki-astari said.